# Displaying which id is missing

Tags: javascript, firefox, yui

I'm having problems to make the same web apps work for different versions of Firefox :

```
var col = [{'id': 'id1'}, {'id': 'id2'}, {'id': 'id3'},{'id': 'id4'},
                {'id': 'id5'}, {'id': 'id6'}, {'id': 'id7'}, {'id': 'id8'}];
doSomething(col);
```

if `id5` doesn't exist my page displays fine in FF8 but in FF 3.5 its not the case.

Is there a way to report or test when an id doesn't exist and display its name (because even in browser console it doesn't display which id is ) ?

**EDIT**

```
var col = [{'id': 'id1'}, {'id': 'id2'}, {'id': 'id3'},{'id': 'id4'},
                    {'id': 'id5'}, {'id': 'id6'}, {'id': 'id7'}, {'id': 'id8'}];
     YAHOO.util.Dom.batch(col, desactivateBtn );

    var desactivateBtn = function(btn){
            YAHOO.widget.Button.getButton(btn.id)._setDisabled(true);
    };
```

I'm using YUI and YAHOO.util.Dom.batch is just so that it applies `desactivateBtn` on all buttons with the ids in `col` (it's similar to jQuery's `$.each` method)

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to post the code responsible for displaying.  An array of small objects doesn't explain the problem (which is most likely in the `doSomething` method and not related to FF or IE)

Comment: thanks for the reply, edited it with doSomething's code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access a property or method on an element that isn't found.

Change:

```
 var desactivateBtn = function(btn){
       YAHOO.widget.Button.getButton(btn.id)._setDisabled(true);
   };
```

To:

```
 var desactivateBtn = function(btn){
       var elem = YAHOO.widget.Button.getButton(btn.id);
       if(elem) elem._setDisabled(true);
   };
```

I've encountered a similar problem with IE swallowing what other browsers would consider an exception. The problem stemmed from using `eval` (it was legacy code, not written by me).  I haven't looked at YAHOO's library, but I wonder if the `getButton` method uses `eval` internally?

edit: If you want to display which items are missing, there's no easy way to do this across browsers since IE8 doesn't have `console.log`.  You could choose to write the output to a debug div element or alert with the message.  I'd probably go with the debug div element.

```
var DEBUG = true;
window.DEBUG_OUTPUT = null;

if(DEBUG) {
   window.DEBUG_OUTPUT = /* create div, append to whatever element */
}
```

Then, you can modify your function to something like:

```
var desactivateBtn = function(btn){
    var elem = YAHOO.widget.Button.getButton(btn.id);
    if(elem) { elem._setDisabled(true); }
    else { window.DEBUG_OUTPUT.innerHTML = window.DEBUG_OUTPUT.innerHTML + ('' + btn.id);
};
```

A couple things to note:

1. I don't like adding to the `window` object, but for console/debug I think it's alright.
2. I have `('' + btn.id)` to coerce non-string ids (like `1`, `2`, etc.) to strings. I'm not sure if this is a problem any more, but I encountered a bug long ago in some browser that setting `innerHTML = 3` would cause an error since 3 isn't a string. I haven't had time to test if this is still a problem in any of the major browsers.

edit2: even better, wrap the `btn.id` in `<p></p>` tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer , testing if the element exist before accessing its properties helped a lot , as for eval i will try to dig in yui code to see if it is used .

Answer (score 2):

You can check for missing elements with:

```
  if (document.getElementById(idValue) === null) {
    console.log("Element " + idValue + " not found");
  }
  else {
    // doSomething ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `length` property of the jQuery collection returned by your selector:

```
if ( $('#field_id').length ) // element exist
{
             // do something
}else{
             // do some other thing
}
```

this is better way to check an id existence. because `length` checks for `null` and `undefined` implicitly and throw no error.